# how to save text from textbox in mysql as utf-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, textbox

when I try to save the text from textbox into mysql database from winforms application, I have a problem with getting the same data and showing in the same textbox, it's shows the '????' please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 2):

Are you executing `SET NAMES UTF8` before populating the data?

Answer (score 1):

1. Is your table UTF8? SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename
2. Is your connection to mysql UTF8? Run SET NAMES UTF8 as your first query.
3. Is your headers and web page set to UTF8?

You need all three in order for everything to work correctly.